# Prevent CommandPrompt window open for startup application

Tags: java, windows, startup, command-prompt

I have a Java application that should run at OS startup.
It is running on Windows XP Professional and I added registry key to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` and used this as key value:

```
java -jar "C:\path\to\app.jar"
```

But this opens `CommandPrompt` window at start up!
How Can I run my application on startup without openning that CommandPrompt window?

Thanks

Comment: try `start javaw "C:\path\to\app.jar"`

Comment: @HernánEche: `javaw -jar "C:\path\to\app.jar"` (without `start`) worked. with start it didn't worked. Thnaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
javaw -jar "C:\path\to\app.jar"
```

Related/Duplicated

[Launch .jar files with command line arguments (but with no console window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711370/launch-jar-files-with-command-line-arguments-but-with-no-console-window)

[Difference between java and javaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129505/difference-between-java-and-javaw)

Comment: Already explained in comments two days ago... and with more context

Comment: @Steve yes, and I was who put the comment, now a community wiki answer for closing the issue.